# To find records between a range - SAILS.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

My requirement is to get 11th to 20th record from the database model.

For example in SQL,

```
  SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

How can i achieve the same in sails.js?

I used .limit(20) to limit 20records ..but if i want to retrieve 11th to 20th records only , then 
i tried to use .skip(10) but it didnt work.

For example,

```
      Table.find(query).sort(qSort).skip(10).limit(20).exec(cb);//limit 20records and skip 10 records
```

Please correct me if iam wrong and help me to solve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the 11th to 20th record:

```
Table.find(query).sort(qSort).skip(10).limit(10).exec(cb);
```

**How this works:**

First, the result of the query is forwarded by `skip` (so we are at 11th record)

Then, a `limit` of 10 is applied (so we are left with 11th to 20th record)

So, regardless of sequence, `skip` is applied first to cursor, and then `limit` is applied on the resultant set.

Hence,

```
Table.find(query).sort(qSort).limit(10).skip(10).exec(cb);
```

would yield the same result as the previous query.

Also, you could try `paginate`:

```
Table.find().sort(qSort).paginate({page: 2, limit: 10});
```

Hope this helps.